# How can one see the file extensions of images and videos on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, graphics, file-extensions

I have taken a few pictures and videos with an iPhone 12, which runs iOS 15. How can one see the file extensions of these images and videos on the iPhone?

I don't see file extensions in the native photo app. I only see the codec information:

[image]

I don’t see these images and videos in the Files app:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the Files App?

Comment: @Allan thanks, I don’t see these images and videos in the Files app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgPnS.png